# Magento1.9 Assign products to different categories for different storeviews

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, category-products

I have a product that I want it to be displayed under **different categories** for **different store views**.

My problem is, for example if I set this product to Macbook Pro for *English* store view, and then in another storeview I set this product to Macbook, then it will change the category I set for the *English* site. It seems I cannot have products set to different categories for different storeviews.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to have different store category trees to do that

More info http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/category-root.html